# Who instituted the Nusach of the Mi SheBerachs that we say?

Tags: tefilla, history, torah-service

Who instituted the Nusach of the Mi SheBerachs that we say for a newborn, for a sick person, after an Aliyah, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

The first mi sheberach appears in the Machzor Vitri

See http://maqom.com/journal/paper35.pdf as well as the Jewish Encyclopedia and [an article](http://thejc.com/judaism/jewish-words/mi-sheberach) written by the Jewish Chronicle.

Comment: How do you know it's the first?

Comment: See http://www.maqom.com/journal/paper35.pdf as well as the Jewish Encyclopedia and an article written by the Jewish Chronicle http://www.thejc.com/judaism/jewish-words/mi-sheberach